# Using variable in subprocess command (Python)

Tags: python

Currently calling:

```
f = open('/tmp/list.txt','w')
f.write(list)
f.close()  # Make sure to close the file before call sub-process.
           # Otherwise, file content will not visible to sub-process.

process = subprocess.Popen('oscommand --file={}'.format(f.name),
                           shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However need to use a variable as an argument which has been generated using [ShortId][1]. Need something like:

```
u=ShortId()
process = subprocess.Popen('oscommand --label "The unique id is "'+u' --file={}'.format(f.name),
                               shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

How is the escaping best handled ?

Comment: Have you tried `.format(str(u))`?

Comment: You are passing a string to the `Popen` command.  You can format the string and save it as a variable before you pass it in.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually easier if you stop trying to make `str` commands with `shell=True` and just use the safer, faster `list` based command with `shell=False` (the default):

```
u=ShortId()
cmd = ['oscommand', '--label', 'The unique id is {}'.format(u), '--file={}'.format(f.name)]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This avoids the risk of either the id or the file name containing shell metacharacters (say, a space) causing the command to be parsed incorrectly (or dangerously, if the string is actively malicious, e.g. a file named `foo;sudo rm -rf /*`).

Also note that there are better ways to do temporary files, whether or not the file is supposed to last after the `Popen` command finishes:

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+t', delete=False) as f:
    f.write(mylist)
... rest of code here ...
```

Alternatively, if the file should be cleaned up automatically after use:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+t') as f:
    f.write(mylist)
    f.flush()
    ... rest of code using temp file ...
```

Comment: Even the last argument can be split as two: `[..., '--file', f.name]`. The `--arg=value` form is intended for situations (not of which I can think of at the moment) where it is more convenient to think of the option and its argument as a single shell word.

Comment: @chepner: That would depend on the argument parsing library in use, but I agree that most would treat it equivalently.

Comment: Tried to switch over to using tempfile before proceding however following error when implementing as shown above by ShadowRanger "Problem reading file '/tmp/tmpULLmrW' "

Comment: @dross: Did you `close` or otherwise delete the Python reference to the `tempfile` before the `Popen`-ed program finished? If it doesn't open the file until after Python deletes it, that would cause problems.

Comment: @ShadowRange: If I try:
 
 with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+t') as f:
    f.write(subnets)
    f.seek(0)

    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip()
    f.close()

Then I get only a partial output of lines until "Problem reading file /tmp/xxx" appears. The file has around 15,000 lines and it would appear to be getting discarded early.

Comment: @dross: Well, first, you're not calling `flush` (`seek` might flush for you, but I'm not sure it's a guarantee on all versions of Python, for all possible file-like objects, but within Python, using the same file object, it shouldn't matter). I'm wondering whether your `/tmp` partition is full though; try running something like `df /tmp` and see whether it's close to full?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: If I try: with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+t') as f: f.write(subnets) f.seek(0) for line in f: print line.rstrip() f.close() Then I get only a partial output of lines until "Problem reading file /tmp/xxx" appears. The file has around 15,000 lines and it would appear to be getting discarded early

Comment: @dross: I don't know what to tell you. If you have a small `/tmp` partition and those 15,000 lines are large, you'd expect to see something like this, but I would hope you'd get an exception when you `flush` if nothing else. You could try passing a `dir` argument to `NamedTemporaryFile` so it goes to a larger partition to be sure. You might also (just in case) `flush` prior to `seek`ing to force any write errors to show up immediately. You don't need to do `f.close()` BTW; the whole point of the `with` block is to make the `close` implicit and guaranteed even in the presence of exceptions.